# LogStash Filter - Aggregate duplicated events and merge it

Tags: ruby, logstash

Given this three LogStash events, a ruby hash

```
{
    "id" => "1",
    "address_unit" => "1",
    "address_sqft" => 1098,
    "address_city" => "NEW YORK"
}

{
    "id" => "1",
    "address_unit" => "1",
    "address_sqft" => 1090,
    "address_city" => "NEW YORK"
}


{
    "id" => "1",
    "address_unit" => "1",
    "address_sqft" => 2000,
    "address_city" => "NEW YORK"
}
```

That should be stored into ES as

```
{
    "id" => "1",
    "address_unit" => "1",
    "address_sqft" => [1098, 1090, 2000],
    "address_city" => "NEW YORK"
}
```

I would like to know if there's some built-in/community filter to achieve it, or how to achieve it using ruby code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you incoming hashes are like `a` and `b` you can use

```
[15] pry(main)> a
=> {"id"=>"1", "address_unit"=>"1", "address_sqft"=>1098, "address_city"=>"NEW YORK"}
[16] pry(main)> b
=> {"id"=>"1", "address_unit"=>"1", "address_sqft"=>1090, "address_city"=>"NEW YORK"}
[17] pry(main)> a.merge(b) {|_, old_val, new_val| old_val==new_val ? old_val :  ([old_val] << new_val).flatten}
=> {"id"=>"1", "address_unit"=>"1", "address_sqft"=>[1098, 1090], "address_city"=>"NEW YORK"}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Awesome and clean solution!